# ReSharper - Un-ignore errors in file

Tags: resharper-7.1

I accidentally asked ReSharper to ignore errors in a C# file. How can I undo the ignoring or errors for a particular file? I'm using ReSharper 7.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok It was easy. Go to 'errors in solution', right click the listed file and select 'stop ignoring errors'.